# VBA onclick event Internet Explorer not working

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I'm new in VBA and i'm trying to automate a web Explorer navigation but with many difficolties. 
I've composed a script that navigate into a web page and search for a code. the result is a table ("dr-table-cell rich-table-cell") with one row that contains the searched item ("02090000062571") displayed as a link to another page. Here the code of that table:

```
<td class="dr-table-cell rich-table-cell" 
    id="formRicercaPdr:pdrTable:0:j_id134">
     <a onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.forms['formRicercaPdr'],'formRicercaPdr:pdrTable:0:j_id136,formRicercaPdr:pdrTable:0:j_id136','');}return false" 
         href="#">02090000062571</a>
 </td>
```

My problem is to click on "02090000062571" href button (is the searched item) and execute the javascript fuction that diplayed another table.

Here my code:

```
Sub TriggerDivClick()
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim div As HTMLDivElement
Dim url As String

url = "some URL"

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate url

While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend
Set pdr_button = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("dr-table-cell rich-table-cell")
For Each a In pdr_button
'here comes the problems 

a.Item(0).FireEvent ("click()")

Next a
```

End Sub

I can find the item but I can't execute the code in order to press the button.
I'm using IE 11.

Thanks for your patience!.

Comment: `ie.Document.getElementById("formRicercaPdr:pdrTable:0:j_id134").getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click`

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME!!! please can you tell me where I can find a complete documentation on DOM and HTML fro beginners. thanks

Comment: Most HTML DOM-related docs are based around using Javascript, but can typically be adapted to VBA without too much trouble.  Maybe start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Comment: @TimWilliams, you should make this an answer, I will vote on it and it should help someone else in the future for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
ie.Document.getElementById("formRicercaPdr:pdrTable:0:j_id13‌​4"). _
     getElementsByTag‌​Name("a")(0).Click
```

Comment: hi tim Sory if a contact you in this way but I'm stack with a button inside an iframe. I'd be happy if you can look just few minutes on that problem. The post is "How to click a button inside IFrame vba" thanks in advance